# Is this a dust mite?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I dropped my phone onto the carpet and picked it up and saw this tiny mite crawling around on the screen.

It is too small to be a bed bug, but perhaps too big to be a dust mite (and doesn't look like the images I found).

Main image is an out of focus image with an iphone simtray for size comparison (the mite about 0.5mm).[image]

The second picture from the left is the only one where I seemed to be able to get its head; all others it was moving away from my camera. I couldn't take any better photos so you'll need to click the image to see the mite in detail.
EDIT: I am in the UK

Comment: Dust mites are microscopic, and have 8 legs only.  You probably have a picture of a carpet beetle larva ('hairy').

Comment: Looks mite-like to me. Definitely doesn't look like any  carpet beetle larvae I've ever seen.  It doesn't  have  clear segments like the  larvae typical  of  beetle species...

Comment: @theforestecologist - I defer to your superior knowledge of insects. Carpet larvae was the only thing I could think of. But they certainly aren't the typical dust mite.